# Installing Cyanongen Mod from a linux host

Tags: android

Is there a way to install cyanogenmod to any android device from a linux host?  Currently, cyanogenmod only provides a windows installer and a beta OSX installer.  I suspect there is a manual method using `fastboot` and `adb`.  I have found several device-specific instructions with little explanation.

Comment: Which device? I've done it on my Nexus 4. You flash a koush recovery or TWRP, boot to recovery, wipe, then sideload the zip. http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mako

Comment: In short? No. More fully: You can flash a custom recovery using `fastboot` from any OS (so long as your device's bootloader is unlocked); once you have a custom recovery, you can `adb sideload` or simply `adb push` the ROM file over to the sdcard and install the ROM from the custom recovery.

Answer (score 0):

The Cyanogenmod wiki has instructions for using `fastboot` and `adb` to install Cyanogenmod.  There is a specific page for each device.

This is the one for Nexus 5: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_hammerhead

General instructions for finding instructions are:

1. Go to https://download.cyanogenmod.org/
2. Find and click on your device on the right.
3. Go ahead and download the latest CM release and recovery release for your device; you'll need them for installation later.
4. Go to the device's wiki.
5. One of the first links will be to the installation wiki for that device.

There is a general pattern across all device but always read the wiki to check for any quirks specific to your device.  The general pattern is:

1. Unlock your bootloader (wipes your device, only needed once per device)

   - `adb reboot bootloader`
   - `fastboot oem unlock`
2. Install the recovery image:  You must do this at least once per device but you don't always need to update the recovery image when you update Cyanogenmod.

   - `adb reboot bootloader`
   - `fastboot flash recovery your_recovery_image.img`
3. Install Cyanogenmod and any other zips to your device like OpenGapps.

   - `adb push filename.zip /sdcard/`
   - `fastboot reboot recovery` (I think this is valid. It's easier than button combos)
   - Using the recovery UI

     - Wipe and/or factory reset your device.
     - Install the zips

*Note that just because your device is listed and has download links doesn't mean your device is currently supported.  Check the dates on the download links.*